# Selenium xpath not found

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I tried the `xpath("//*[@id='btn-conv-view']")` to click button in selenium web driver java code and it didn't seem to work.  The html is below:

```
<button id="btn-conv-view" class="btn btn-absolute btn-view-dd" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" title="More view options" data-action="menu"> 
    <span class="icon-text" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1443572970628_2273">Sort by date</span>
    <b class="icon icon-chevron-down" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1443572970628_2377"></b>
</button>
```

Comment: HTML snippet:  <button id="btn-conv-view" class="btn btn-absolute btn-view-dd" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" title="More view options" data-action="menu">
 <span class="icon-text" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1443572970628_2273">Sort by date</span>
  <b class="icon icon-chevron-down" id="yui_3_16_0_1_1443572970628_2377">
  </b>
</button>

Comment: element is probably inside the iframe

Comment: Didnt seem to work??? Context and clear expected output vs actual output. Also be sure to say whether actual error logs or similar were generated, and share them.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Like Saifur said, it is probably within an iFrame.

Comment: Actually the code is trying to click a "Sort by date" button in yahoomail after logging in.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have shown us. The problem lies in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use any of this ways to find element you needed:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-conv-view")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('btn-conv-view')")).click();

driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#btn-conv-view")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is unique in the page then you can use id locator instead going for xpath.

You can use id like below:-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-conv-view")).click();
```

You can also click using JavascriptExecutor which operates directly on DOM. You can find the locator according to your convenience and change it in below code

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("btn-conv-view"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```